# Why does the woman have to go through the pain of giving birth?

Tags: sex, husband-wife, pain

In Islam we are treated fairly and equally in a just manner. However, a woman is told that if her husband calls her then she has to answer, she has to asker permission to go out, she has to serve her husband and take care of him. Then if the husband need to fulfil his sexual desires she has to leave what she is doing and go to him. If the husband goes to sleep when he is angry because his wife did not let him touch her then the Angels curse the wife. Why? I mean the wife has to feel all this pain just to fulfil his desires? The man won't care because he doesn't feel the pain the woman goes through. He doesn't have to carry the baby for nine months then feel the pain of giving birth. What if the wife is scared of giving birth because of the pain? It's all fun and games for the men yet they are the ones that should not get upset? What about the pain women go through? Why don't the men give birth since they are made as the stronger ones? Since they are allowed to go out without a Mahram?

So my question is why does the woman have to feel pain to have children but not the man?

Comment: You have looked from one perspective only, why don't you try looking from the other??? Without the man, the woman would have no one take care of her. She would also not be able to fulfil her desires. She won't have a guaranteed source of food. The husband works and does his best to make his wife happy. And many many other stuff.

Comment: That was in the past, @AbdelRahmanShamel, today women are starting to take care of themselves.

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel Actually I disagree. A woman can work and earn money to look after herself. A woman can run her the whole house. A woman can multitask but the man cannot do all at the same time. Even if things don't go well she can always live at her parent's house or with a friend.

Comment: So what do you suggest?? To stop the human race by not marrying? Or grow babies in test tubes?? This is the nature of humans, Allah created the female for the male, and the male for the female to be a consort for each other, and help each other in their lives. Furthermore, what is greater than the extremely high rank Allah has given mothers in the Quraan?? Even that is sufficient for a mother to endure and be proud. The Prophet also told one of the companions who was carrying his mom on his back for hajj that he didn't even compensate a sigh of pain of giving birth!

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel tbh u answer sounds quite rude. I don't know if that was the intention or not. My question was why do the men not give birth instead? I never said we should stop reproducing. Or is there a particular reason as to why women were chosen to give birth? In Christianity they believe that the woman gives birth because Eve told Adam to eat the fruit from the forbidden tree. So now all women have to be punished in this way. I am looking for the Islamic reasoning behind it now.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to be rude at all. I'm sorry if it sounded that way. And that belief of christianity that you mentioned is false. It was satan that told Adam and Eve to eat from the tree as mentioned in the Quraan. So, women weren't punished for such a myth. The idea that women are responsible for giving birth, is the difference in the structures and the nature of humans. Males are different than females. Females are given the power to endure such pain. A male cannot withstand a few moments of it!

Comment: As-written, this really looks more like a rant than an actual *question*; it completely lacks any sort of focus.

Comment: @goldPseudo It is not a rant. I have given reasons as to why I think it is unfair on women. The question is clear so I don't see why it has been put on hold. Simply because you cannot answer it?

Answer (score 1):

First you have lots of questions in one question, these questions is not answered by one simple answer. However, i can sum up your questions as "why woman are not equal with man?"
First of all people are equal as soul and human in front of Allah, but there are some physical differences and these differences bring different tests, like giving birth. After all everything in this world is an exam for us to learn what and  who we are.
Other then this basic thing, some of your questions are just some tradition of Muslim society, which are not influenced by Quran.

Quran see humans as equal:

> breathed some of My spirit into divine touch. When God created him"(or her in this sense). [Noble Quran 15:29 See also 32:9]

This is my basic answer but you can read more from **[this site:](http://www.islamswomen.com/articles/do_muslim_women_have_rights.php)**

> From the marital standpoint, the Quran clearly indicates in Surahs 30:20 and 42:11 that marriage is not just an inevitable evil, marriage is not somebody getting married to his master or slave, but rather to his partner.
>
> "Among His Signs is this, that he created for you mates from among
>   yourselves, that they may dwell in tranquility with them, and He has
>   put love and mercy between your (hearts): Verily in that are signs for
>   those who reflect." [Noble Quran 30:21]
>
> There are numerous verses in the Quran to the same effect.
>
> Secondly, the approval and consent of the girl to marriage is a
>   prerequisite for the validity of marriage in Islam. She has the right
>   to say yes or no.
>
> Husbands' and wives' duties are mutual responsibilities. They might
>   not be identical duties, but the totality of rights and
>   responsibilities are balanced. The Quran says:
>
> "Women have the same rights (in relation to their husbands) as are
>   expected in all decency from them, while men stand a step above them."
>   [Noble Quran 2:228]
>
> This only specifies the degree of responsibility, not privilege, in
>   man's role as provider, protector, maintainer, and leader of the
>   family. The same Surah speaks about divorce, about consultation
>   between husband and wife, even in the case of divorce. When there are
>   family disputes, first the Quran appeals to reason and the
>   consideration of positive aspects of one's spouse,
>
> "Dwell with your wives in kindness for even if you hate them, you
>   might be hating someone in whom God has placed so much good." [Noble
>   Quran 4:19]
>
> If that appeal does not succeed, and problems between the husband and
>   wife continue, there are measures that can be applied. Some of these
>   measures are done privately between husband and wife. Some of them
>   might appear harsh, but there are qualifications to restrict excessive
>   or abusive use of these measures. These measures are considered an
>   attempt to save a marriage rather than break a family apart. If the
>   situation does not improve, even with the limitation and prevention of
>   excesses, the next step is a family council. One arbiter from his
>   family and one from her family should sit together with the couple and
>   try to resolve the problems.

You can find more ***[here](http://www.islamswomen.com/articles/equality_of_men_and_women.php)*** and ***[here](http://www.islamswomen.com/articles/women_in_quran_and_sunnah.php)*** and ***[here](http://www.islamswomen.com/articles/ayshah_bint_abu_bakr.php)***